# How to create shareable testkit with Junit?

Tags: java, maven, junit

Let's say I've created a modular project in `maven`, which has `api` interface defined in `myproject-api`, and two implementations of this interface in `myproject-impl` and `myproject-impl2`.

```
myproject-api
myproject-impl
myproject-impl2
```

I want to create a single test suite, that I could run against both implementations. Of course in the future, I could add another implementation and I would also want to test it using these common tests.

What would be the best practice to achieve that kind of shared tests with junit?

Example of the interface (in `myproject-api`):

```
public interface SmallLettersSource {
   String read();
}
```

Implementations:

- in module `myproject-impl`:

```
class ASource implements SmallLettersSource {

    @Override
    public String read() {
        return "a";
    }
}
```

- in module `myproject-impl2`:

```
class BSource implements SmallLettersSource {

    @Override
    public String read() {
        return "b";
    }
}
```

And test (I would also want to add it to `myproject-api`):

```
@Test
void test() {
    assert(source.read().equals(source.read().toLowerCase()));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with the following solution:

1. in `myproject-api` I created class `CommonTestSuite`, which is returning list of `DynamicTest` objects:

   ```
   public class CommonTestSuite {

       private final Source source;

       public CommonTestSuite(Source source) {
            this.source = source;
       }

       public Collection<DynamicTest> tests() {

           return Arrays.asList(
               dynamicTest("Should return only lowercase.", this::testLowercase),
               dynamicTest("Should return only one letter.", this::testLength)
           );

       }

       void testLowercase() {
            assert(source.read().equals(source.read().toLowerCase()));
       }

       void testLength() {
            assert(source.read().size() == 1);
       }
   }
   ```

   2. Then in tests of my implementation modules, I need only to do:

   ```
   class MyProjectImplTest {

       @TestFactory
       Collection<DynamicTest> test() {
          return new CommonTestSuite(new ASource()).tests();
       }
   }
   ```

   and for other modules, I need to do a similar setup. This way I can share common tests between various modules.